# MSBuild 15 NuGet restore and build

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild, nuget

I'm trying to get the new MSBuild NuGet restore feature to work and having an odd problem.

If I do:

```
msbuild.exe mySolution.sln /p:Configuration=Release
```

I get an error about missing packages. This is expected behaviour.
However, if I do:

```
msbuild.exe mySolution.sln /p:Configuration=Release /t:restore
```

MSBuild "succeeds" but just creates an obj folder with some files relating to the NuGet restore i.e. no bin\Release\ folder.

In order to restore **and** build I have to issue both commands above (restore first, obviously).

I have upgrade all of the packages.config files to use the latest PackageReference in the .csproj file.

***Is there a way to both restore and build using a single command?***

Answer (score 54, accepted):

MSBuild 15.5 will introduce [a `/restore` flag](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/pull/2414) that implements this functionality.

Before that, it is theoretically possible to run both a restore and build in the same invocation (`/t:Restore;Build`) but it is **unsafe** as MSBuild may cache project files and not see changes made by a NuGet restore. The `/restore` option will clear all the affected caches before resuming with the normal build.

Comment: We do a specific nuget restore on our solution and just live with it.

Comment: As I saw that the default "nuget restore" used msbuild 14.0 and failed I tried to find the solution for "nuget restore" with a specific version. But with your proposal of the "/t" switch everything builds automagically. Thank you Martin!

Comment: If your nuget.exe itself is the older version it will not "see" that MS Build 15 is installed and will fall back to version 14 as the default.

Comment: msbuild.exe /t:Restore does absolutely nothing. It says there are no packages to restore. If you open the same solution in visual studio, right click solution, then choose restore packages, it restores them all. Why are these tools so poorly documented?

Comment: This only works for projects using PackageReference and not for classic packages.config projects

Comment: just wanna clarify - to execute both restore and build run **msbuild project.sln /restore**

Comment: @Shpand "MSBUILD : error MSB1001: Unknown switch.
Switch: /restore"

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen that happens when you use a too old msbuild version, e.g. the one in .net framework. Use the visual studio 2019+ developer command prompt to get more current versions of msbuild