# Jenkins - Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, nuget-package-restore

When I build .NET Standard 2.0 Library on Jenkins build server

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.302\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(198,5): error : Assets file 'C:\Jenkins\workspace\<Project>\Sources\Library\obj\project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file. [C:\Jenkins\workspace\<Project>\Sources\Library\Library.csproj]
```

I got an error above in build log.

I searched about error and I found [solution](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/3762)

However, when running:

```
dotnet restore <Solution Name>
```

the solution does not help me out when I clean my workspace before build starts.

Therefore, I insert command before MSBuild but I failed with

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.302\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(198,5): error : Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces, version 2.8.0 was not found. It might have been deleted since NuGet restore. Otherwise, NuGet restore might have only partially completed, which might have been due to maximum path length restrictions. [C:\Jenkins\workspace\<Project>\Sources\Web\Web.csproj]
```

According to [Solution reference](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/3762), maybe upgrade *Nuget Package Installer* could help me out. But I do not know how can I upgrade *Nuget Package Installer* by command line...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I had the same problem, getting the same error:

> `error : Package <package> was not found. It might have been deleted since NuGet restore. Otherwise, NuGet restore might have only partially completed, which might have been due to maximum path length restrictions. [<path>]`

I was able to solve it using `MSBuild /t:restore` instead of `dotnet restore`.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#restore-target

Answer (score 9):

**UPDATE**: It's worth mentioning that problems in Jenkins are discussed in depth in this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48896487/213871).

The hint by @Mat didn't work for me: the `/t:restore` is currently not able to restore nuget packages for projects using `package.config`, as I mention [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53637632/213871). What worked for me is the following:

```
call "%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"
nuget restore CodeBinder.sln
MSBuild Solution.sln /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="Any CPU" /t:build /restore
pause
```

It basically requires to download the nuget CLI from official site[1], Windows x86 Commandline section. The switch `/restore` , as pointed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46774338/213871), fixed the partially completed Nuget restore error, similarly to `MSBuild /t:restore`, but it can be done in conjunction with `/t:build`.

[1] https://www.nuget.org/downloads

Comment: This solution worked for me. My solution have some projects with package.config and just one with package references.