# Dot net nuget restore - restore: invalid arguments error

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I'm trying to compile my C# project using the restore command:

```
bat "nuget.exe restore \"C:(...)\\Bin\\msbuild.exe\" mycoolproj.sln \t:Clean,Build"
```

And I get `restore: invalid arguments` error.

Then I changed to `/t:Clean,Build`, and I get `"Unknown option 't:Clean,Build'"`.

Do you know what is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `/t:Clean,Build` is a `msbuild.exe` switch and currently you can't pass switches to `msbuild` using `nuget.exe`. Alternatively because you're building your project you can tell `msbuild.exe` to restore those packages for you:

```
msbuild.exe solution.sln /t:rebuild,restore
```

Also in [MSBuild 15.5](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/pull/2414) and later there is a `/restore` switch which is [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46773698/msbuild-15-nuget-restore-and-build):

```
msbuild.exe solution.sln /restore /t:rebuild
```

You can learn more about MSBuild CLI [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference) and NuGet CLI [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-exe-cli-reference).